# Accessing file in main domain folder from subdomain app

Tags: asp.net, xml, subdomain, server.mappath

I have a web app in a subdomain, where I want to uptain access to a file located in the main domain. Is that possible?

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../www/file.xml"));
```

Where "www" in the main folder. The "../" doesnt work.

To be crystal clear. Im trying to load a xml file into a XDocument object:

```
Data = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/file.xml");
```

Works fine. But I want the path to be in a folder on the main domain. How can I do that? If its possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you will have to specify the full url like `c:/wwwroot/site/file.xml`

Comment: so no classes or anything that can handle it for me?

Comment: Nope sorry :/ had the problem myself

Comment: Roger that. I got hold of the complete path from my web hotel provider, so it works now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just create a symlink (`mklink` command in cmd) and use it just as if it were a folder inside your subdomain directory.
You need an admin privileges do create a symlink.